# Get a list from the dictionary key in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries. e.g:

```
list = [ {list1}, {list2}, .... ]
```

One of the key-value pair in each dictionary is another dictionary.
Ex

```
list1 = { "key1":"val11", "key2":"val12", "key3":{"inkey11":"inval11","inkey12":"inval12"} }
list2 = { "key1":"val21", "key2":"val22", "key3":{"inkey21":"inval21","inkey22":"inval22"} }
```

I was thinking of getting all values of `key3` in the all the dictionaries into a list.
Is it possible to access them directly (something like `list[]["key3"]` ) or do we need to iterate through all elements to form the list?

I have tried

> requiredlist = list [ ] ["key3"].

But it doesn't work. 
The final outcome I wanted is

`requiredlist = [ {"inkey11":"inval11","inkey12":"inval12"}, {"inkey21":"inval21","inkey22":"inval22"} ]`

Comment: What have you tried? Please be sure to read the About for StackOverflow, and the guide to asking good questions. stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask | stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) would work well here:

```
[innerdict["key3"] for innerdict in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list1["key3"]
```

Notice that `list1` and `list2` as you defined them are dictionaries, not lists - and the value of `"key3"` is a *set*, not a list. You're confounding `{}` with `[]`, they have different meanings.

Comment: key3 contains not a string called 'dict1' but contains a dictionary called dict1. did you see any quotes around dict1 in the question?

Comment: If I write `dict1` without quotes, then it won't compile, because it's unhashable and you can't put it in a set. So either way, the sample code in the question won't work. Anyway, I removed that part of my answer, until OP posts some code that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

To access an element is a dictionary you must do the following:

```
dict_name[key_name] #in this case: list1[key3]
```

Try this:

```
newlist = []
list = [{ "key1":"val11", "key2":"val12", "key3":{dict1} },{ "key1":"val21", "key2":"val22", "key3":{dict1} }]
for innerdict in list:
    newlist += list(innerdict["key3"]) 
print newlist #This will give all the values of key3 in all the dictionaries
```

if `dict1` in the lists is a set then the above example will work good, but if it is a dictionary then it will give a list but ONLY the keys will be included so if it is a dictionary try this:

```
newlist = []
list = [{ "key1":"val11", "key2":"val12", "key3":{dict1} },{ "key1":"val21", "key2":"val22", "key3":{dict1} }]
for innerdict in list:
    newlist.append(innerdict["key3"]) 
print newlist #This will give all the values of key3 in all the dictionaries
```